# On clicking the search button , The selected option is not getting inserted to my PHP file and hence the query is not getting executed

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

[No response on clicking search button . Nor does the URL transfers to localhost/homeservices/searchproviders.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnCiH.png)**I am working on my project ,I want to transfer the selected values of city and profession to searchprovider.php file .** I think the control is not getting transferred to searchprovider.php because i tried an alert script to check if it works ! But it didn't . Can someone please help me out !! Also i have connected to mysql using PDO method .

Thanks in advance !

Here's my index.php [C:\xampp\htdocs\homeservices\index.php]

```
<?php

include_once "./include/header.php";



$cities = ["Ahmednagar", "Akola", "Akot", "Amalner", "Ambejogai", "Amravati", "Anjangaon", "Arvi", "Aurangabad", "Bhiwandi", "Dhule", "Kalyan-Dombivali", "Ichalkaranji", "Kalyan-Dombivali", "Karjat", "Latur", "Loha", "Lonar", "Lonavla", "Mahad", "Malegaon", "Malkapur", "Mangalvedhe", "Mangrulpir", "Manjlegaon", "Manmad", "Manwath", "Mehkar", "Mhaswad", "Mira-Bhayandar", "Morshi", "Mukhed", "Mul", "Greater Mumbai*", "Murtijapur", "Nagpur", "Nanded-Waghala", "Nandgaon", "Nandura", "Nandurbar", "Narkhed", "Nashik", "Navi Mumbai", "Nawapur", "Nilanga", "Osmanabad", "Ozar", "Pachora", "Paithan", "Palghar", "Pandharkaoda", "Pandharpur", "Panvel", "Parbhani", "Parli", "Partur", "Pathardi", "Pathri", "Patur", "Pauni", "Pen", "Phaltan", "Pulgaon", "Pune", "Purna", "Pusad", "Rahuri", "Rajura", "Ramtek", "Ratnagiri", "Raver", "Risod", "Sailu", "Sangamner", "Sangli", "Sangole", "Sasvad", "Satana", "Satara", "Savner", "Sawantwadi", "Shahade", "Shegaon", "Shendurjana", "Shirdi", "Shirpur-Warwade", "Shirur", "Shrigonda", "Shrirampur", "Sillod", "Sinnar", "Solapur", "Soyagaon", "Talegaon Dabhade", "Talode", "Tasgaon", "Thane", "Tirora", "Tuljapur", "Tumsar", "Uchgaon", "Udgir", "Umarga", "Umarkhed", "Umred", "Uran", "Uran Islampur", "Vadgaon Kasba", "Vaijapur", "Vasai-Virar", "Vita", "Wadgaon Road", "Wai", "Wani", "Wardha", "Warora", "Warud", "Washim", "Yavatmal", "Yawal", "Yevla"];
?>

<h2 class="text-center" style="margin-top: 20px">Home Services</h2>
<hr>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom: 60px;">

<form method="post" action="scripts/searchproviders.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-5">
            <label for="">City</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="city" id="city">
                <option value="none">-- Select City --</option>
                <?php foreach ($cities as $city) : ?>
                <option value="<?= $city ?>"> <?= $city ?>
                </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-5">
            <label for="">Who's Required </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="profession" id="profession">
                <option value="none" name="profession">-- Select Profession --</option>
                <option value="electrician" name="profession">Electrician</option>
                <option value="plumber" name="profession">Plumber</option>
                <option value="mobile" name="profession">Beautician</option>
                <option value="mobile" name="profession">Maid</option>
                <option value="mobile" name="profession">Mobile Repairer</option>
                <option value="mobile" name="profession">Photographer</option>
                <option value="mobile" name="profession">Carpenter</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-2">
            <label for="">Action</label>
            <input type="button" id="search"  class="form-control btn btn-success" type="button" value="Search"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="providers" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Profession</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='5'>Select city and profession..</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>



<?php include_once "./include/footer.php";?>
```

///Here's my searchproviders.php  [C:\xampp\htdocs\homeservices\scripts\searchproviders.php]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<?php

require_once 'helpers.php';
echo'<script>alert("Hiii")</script>';
if (isset($_POST['city']) && isset($_POST['profession'])) {
    
    
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $profession = $_POST['profession'];
    $servername ="localhost";
    $username ="root";
    $password ="sarasaeed";
    $dbname="services";
            
    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=services; charset=utf8','root','sarasaeed');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM providers WHERE city='$city' AND profession='$profession'";
        $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);  
        $statement->execute();  
        $providers = $statement->fetchAll();
        if($providers){
            foreach($providers as $key=>$value) {
                echo "<html>";
                echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$providers->name</td>"."<td>$providers->adder1</td>"."<td>$providers->profession</td"."<td><a href='booking.php?provider=></td>";
            }
        }else{
            echo"NO PROVIDERS FOUND";
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
                $conn = null;
            }
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: You can check in the debug panel (usually, press F12 on your browser), into the network tab, look what happen to the form submit request. Is the status 200 OK ? Can you see your content ?

Comment: No i cannot see my response there. But the status is 200 . What does that mean ?

Comment: it means nothing. what "alert" did you try and how exactly it "works"? Did you try simply `var_dump($_POST);die;`? And what do you see in your browser at all?

Comment: <script>alert("Hii")</script>

Comment: Can you edit your original message and explain your file structure ? Where are each file in your project directory ? It might be because the path is erroneous.

Comment: @Kulvar , Yes sir i did that plz check out

Comment: Try `action="/homeservices/scripts/searchproviders.php"` (absolute path) or `action="./scripts/searchproviders.php"` (relative path) instead. Without a leading . or /, behavior can be confusing. When you submit, what is the URL in your browser ?

Comment: No change in the URL

Answer (score -1):

try to change HTML Forms to `<form method="post" action="../searchproviders.php">`
delete scripts.

Comment: then add <?php include_once "scripts/searchproviders.php";?> on your index.php file
if works than your FORM is not good.

Comment: What do u mean by form is not good ? @Derkh7 n also plz specify how to get it to work ?

Comment: its work whit added <?php include_once "scripts/searchproviders.php";?>?? . .... i mean FORM HTML he can find your searchproviders.php on from.